# How to fix AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'find'"?

Tags: python-3.x, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from cgitb import text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'https://www.marketplacehomes.com/rent-a-home/'
result = requests.get(website)
content = result.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_=('tt-rental-row'))

for list in lists:
    location = list.find('span', class_="renta;-adress")
    beds = list.find('span', class_="renta;-beds")
    baths = list.find('span', class_="renta;-beds")
    availability = list.find('span', class_="rental-date-available")
    info = [location, beds, baths, availability]
    print(info)
```

If I try to run the last line of code, I get:

```
"IndentationError: expected an indented block"
```

If I try to run each indentation separately I get:

```
">>> location = list.find('span', class_="renta;-adress")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'list' has no attribute 'find'"
```

I'm new to `Python` and I'm kinda stuck, can anyone please help me?

Comment: Are you sure you've spelt the html classes correctly? `renta;-adress` doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: You're actually correct, I've realized, came back here and saw your comment lol. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *Your code never runs the for-loop cause your selection never matches the elements in HTML. They are generated dynamically based on data from another ressource and requests do not render websites like a browser, it only uses static contents from response.*

*Be aware not to use [built-in keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) they will cause errors, especialy  in your case `list.find()` will raise one cause the type object 'list' do not has an attribute called `find`. You could simply check these things using `type()`*

```
type(soup)
-> its a bs4.BeautifulSoup

type(soup.find_all('div', class_=('tt-rental-row')))
-> its a bs4.element.ResultSet

type(list)
-> its a type
```

---

**So how to get your goal?**

You could also use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to directly create a `DataFrame` and [slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-basics) it to your needs:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json('https://app.tenantturner.com/listings-json/2679')
```

Output:

```
    id  dateActivated   latitude    longitude   address city    state   zip photo   title   ... baths   dateAvailable   rentAmount  acceptPets  applyUrl    btnUrl  btnText virtualTour propertyType    enableWaitlist
0   83600   8/22/2022   35.750499   -86.393972  4481 Jack Faulk St  Murfreesboro    TN  37127   https://ttimages.blob.core.windows.net/propert...   4481 Jack Faulk St  ... 2.0 Now 2195    cats, small dogs, large dogs    https://app.propertyware.com/pw/application/#/...   https://app.tenantturner.com/qualify/4481-jack...   Schedule Viewing    None    Single Family   False
1   100422  8/31/2022   30.277607   -95.472842  213 Skybranch Court Conroe  TX  77304   https://ttimages.blob.core.windows.net/propert...   213 Skybranch Court ... 2.5 Now 2100    cats, small dogs, large dogs    https://app.propertyware.com/pw/application/#/...   https://app.tenantturner.com/qualify/213-skybr...   Schedule Viewing    None    Condo Unit  False
2   106976  7/27/2022   28.274720   -82.298077  8127 Olive Brook Dr Wesley Chapel   FL  33545   https://ttimages.blob.core.windows.net/propert...   8127 Olive Brook Dr ... 2.0 Now 2650    no pets https://app.propertyware.com/pw/application/#/...   https://app.tenantturner.com/qualify/8127-oliv...   Schedule Viewing    None    Single Family   False
3   116188  8/15/2022   42.624023   -83.144614  735 Grace Ave   Rochester Hills MI  48307   https://ttimages.blob.core.windows.net/propert...   735 Grace Ave   ... 2.0 Now 1600    cats, small dogs, large dogs    https://app.propertyware.com/pw/application/#/...   https://app.tenantturner.com/qualify/735-grace...   Schedule Viewing    None    Single Family   False
4   126846  8/22/2022   32.046455   -81.071181  1810 E 41st St  Savannah    GA  31404   https://ttimages.blob.core.windows.net/propert...   1810 E 41st St  ... 1.0 Now 1395    small dogs  https://app.propertyware.com/pw/application/#/...   https://app.tenantturner.com/qualify/1810-e-41...   Schedule Viewing    None    Single Family   True

...
91 rows × 22 columns
```

##### Example:

To show only specifc columns, simply pass a list of there names.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_json('https://app.tenantturner.com/listings-json/2679')[['address', 'city','state', 'zip', 'title', 'beds', 'baths','dateAvailable']]
```

##### Output

```
    address beds    baths   dateAvailable
0   4481 Jack Faulk St  4   2.0 Now
1   213 Skybranch Court 3   2.5 Now
2   8127 Olive Brook Dr 3   2.0 Now
3   735 Grace Ave   3   2.0 Now
4   1810 E 41st St  3   1.0 Now
... ... ... ... ...

91 rows × 4 columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the word `list` is a built-in keyword in python you can't use it as variable name try another name

```
for myList in lists:
    location = myList.find('span', class_="renta;-adress")
    beds = myList.find('span', class_="renta;-beds")
    baths = myList.find('span', class_="renta;-beds")
    availability = myList.find('span', class_="rental-date-available")
    info = [location, beds, baths, availability]
    print(info)
```

Comment: Ok, I tried to run it exactly like that but I still get the same error.

Comment: If I try to run, for example, "location" I get "location = myList.find('span', class_="renta;-adress")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myList' is not defined"